# Dash - html.P too width when add text

Tags: html, plotly-dash, altair

What function can I use in order to add a comment below a `html.Iframe` plot in `Dash`?

I am using `html.P` but this works awful making the plot too width once I add the text.

```
html.Iframe(id='my-graph', style={'display': 'block', 'width': '400%', 'height': '100%'}),
html.P(id='text-2', children='when I write something here the graph becomes too width.'),
```

Additional finding: I noted the issue appears when the text's extension is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of the `html.P` component to a certain value you'd like under `style`, like this:

```py
html.P("Some text", style={"width": "10%"})
```

Possible width values are explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)